# Free random human face generator

Tags: java, graphics

Does anybody know of a free library component that generates random 2D human faces?

Searching, I came up with [FaceGen](http://www.facegen.com/) which however isn't free, so it won't do.

Ideally I'm looking for something in Java, but if the licensing permits it, I can port it to Java. I don't really need anything super sophisticated, nor even very parameterizable, just something that spits out still 2D images.

Comment: How about link MakeHuman (an OSS person generator) to a Java raytracer?

Comment: Thanks! You should post that as an answer. Ideally, I'd want something easier, but that's a very valid suggestion, I didn't know MakeHuman - the quality looks awesome and this would give a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be a stretch, but you could use [Makehuman](http://www.makehuman.org/) and hook it up to [Sunflow](http://sunflow.sourceforge.net/) (a OSS Java raytracer. It's really realistic).

I'm not sure if Makehuman has a CLI interface, but if it does, you can export the 3D model and then render it with Sunflow.